# What Ubuntu distribution do I want?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, distro-recommendation

I am a video gamer. I also want Linux, so I came to Ubuntu. Only one question remains: Do I want the "cutting-edge" Ubuntu 13.04, supported for 9 months, or the 12.04 "extended support" version, supported for 4 years? Or do I want something else entirely?

Comment: Well.. What hardware do you have?

Comment: Answer: 12.04 LTS, and then.... noext LTS and so on. IMHO

Comment: Hardware: iBUYPOWER laptop with NVIDIA 680m graphics card , 1 TB hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking at this like a gamer, then you have to go with the latest, at this time, 13.04. It has better video performance, updated kernel, updated drivers and enhancements to Unity for performance. So at the end, games will run better on 13.04.

Since you are looking at this as a gamer, then the extended support is irrelevant since most gamers tend to update their system when something new comes along. Also 13.04 is not cutting edge. It's another stable release that offers the latest version of Ubuntu. If you want cutting edge I suggest to read [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-correctly-install-an-nvidia-video-card/61433#61433) and trying out the latest drivers.

But at the end, if you want the best performance for your games, always go with the latest. The support is of less importance since when a new version comes out, you will probably update to it. I say this as another gamer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you a piece of advice: don't jump headfirst into this change, OR ELSE YOU WILL BECOME ONE OF US - TECH WIZARD PROBLEM SOLVERS.

XD

Now then, go for 13.04 current release, and update regularly. Use Wine for your games. Ask for help when you need it, but do a quick google search first.

Welcome to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and the welcome! As my computer is a laptop, I won't be able to update the hardware, but I'll be sure to check if Wine can run my games. Then I'll get the latest Ubuntu version. Again, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You want the distribution recommended by the game creators!    If they do not support Linux, then don't spend time trying to make that game run under Linux.

For Steam I understand that they target 12.04 LTS.  This would be a good start.